# WPF Net Framework 3.5 Window Metro Style

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, microsoft-metro, mahapps.metro, modern-ui

I want to make Window with Metro style.

I found the 3 following libraries:

http://elysium.asvishnyakov.com/en/

https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro

http://mui.codeplex.com/

All are for Net Framework 4+.
Is there anything for 3.5?

I also tried to make it on my own (Didnt finish - still need to design it and add Resize [which I dont know how]) but I dont really like how it's made...:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" x:Class="Windows_Hider.MainWindow"
        Title="Windows Hider" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        AllowsTransparency="True"
    ResizeMode="CanResize" WindowStyle="None" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Icon="windowshider.ico">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Content="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" Background="Transparent"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0">
                <Button ToolTip="minimize" Background="White">
                    <Grid Width="30" Height="25">
                        <TextBlock Text="0" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="3.5,0,0,3" />
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
                <Grid Margin="1,0,1,0">
                    <Button x:Name="Restore"  ToolTip="restore" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Grid Width="30" Height="25" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                            <TextBlock Text="2" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="2,0,0,1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="Maximize" ToolTip="maximize">
                        <Grid Width="31" Height="25">
                            <TextBlock Text="1" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="2,0,0,1" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Button  x:Name="Close" ToolTip="close">
                    <Grid Width="30" Height="25">
                        <TextBlock Text="r" FontFamily="Marlett" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,0,1" />
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it took me few days but in the end I managed to do something.

I had to make it by myself because there's no Metro Window for Net Framework 3.5.

I combined some of the references below:

[Launch window's System Menu on custom window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410121/launch-windows-system-menu-on-custom-window)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107994/Taskbar-with-Window-Maximized-and-WindowState-to-N

http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

http://codekong.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/custom-window-style-and-accounting-for-the-taskbar/

http://blog.creativeitp.com/posts-and-articles/c-sharp/simple-methods-to-drag-and-resize-your-c-transparent-wpf-application-with-the-windowstyle-property-set-to-none/

[this is the final solution](http://sdrv.ms/1bHRIBw)

Known problems / bugs:
1. When resizing the arrow cursor appear instead of the resizing cursor.
2. Designer cant display the custom window.
3. When maximizing, randomly there's blue (the color of the borders) in big area of the screen - for split second

If you can fix any of the problems above it will be even better but I am satisfied with what I achieved.

**EDIT:**
Updated to allow resize modes (also added sample)

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy to do this yourself... all you need to do is copy the `Style` that you see in the `Metro` UI, as you call it. To start you off, here is a very simple `Style` that changes the `ControlTemplate` of the `Button` elements to remove their default look:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Of course, you'll want something to happen when the user moves their mouse pointer over the `Button` and you can do that by adding `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` to the `ControlTemplate`. You can find a full example of this in the [ControlTemplate Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx) page on MSDN.

The other controls `Metro`-style controls can be easily developed by creating simple `ControlTemplate`s in the same way. Basically, you'll just need to remove the default WPF look and for the most part, just replace it with just a `ContentPresenter` as in the above example, or an `ItemsPresenter` for collection controls. Luckily the `Metro` look is very plain and simple, just remember to keep everything spaced out and plain.

To address another point you mad about resizing; you can set the `Window.ResizeMode` property to `CanResizeWithGrip` to add the resize grip in the bottom right corner of the `Window` as is often seen in these applications.

Comment: 1. I cant find window ControlTemplate and even if I could find, I believe I wont be able to change it to fit my needs (so it will have windows 8 theme). 2. I want to have regular resize from border, without the grip in the right corner (but with WindowStyle=None and without seeing the Window's Border added because of the CanResize)