# Launch window's System Menu on custom window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, contextmenu

I would like to call the `ContextMenu` when you click on application's icon or right mouse click on the title bar of application.

This is the `ContextMenu` I mean:

[image]

I need it because I made custom control that acts like window.
I need this behavior to complete my control.

**EDIT:**
Leo Lorenzo Luis asked for me code:

https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=c3392940f5cf5f74&id=C3392940F5CF5F74%21107&authkey=!APd2X3tDxWRfpL4

or:

My MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <!--<Grid>
        <Border Name="TopBorder" BorderThickness="0.5,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Blue"/>
        <Border Name="RightBorder" BorderThickness="0,0.5,0,0" BorderBrush="Red"/>
        <Border Name="BottomBorder" BorderThickness="0,0,0.5,0" BorderBrush="Green"/>
        <Border Name="LeftBorder" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5" BorderBrush="Orange"/>
        <Grid Margin="0.5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StatusBar Background="Transparent" MouseDoubleClick="TriggerMaximize" MouseDown="StatusBar_MouseDown">
                    <Image Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
                    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Content="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                </StatusBar>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button x:Name="Minimize" ToolTip="Minimize" Content="0" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}" Click="TriggerMinimize"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Restore" ToolTip="Restore" Content="2" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}"  Visibility="Collapsed" Click="TriggerMaximize"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Maximize" ToolTip="Maximize" Content="1" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}" Click="TriggerMaximize"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Close" ToolTip="Close" Content="r" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}" Click="TriggerClose"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>-->

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
        <Border Name="TopBorder" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderBrush ="#007ACC" BorderThickness="0.5"/>
        <Border Name="RightBorder" DockPanel.Dock="Right" BorderBrush ="#007ACC" BorderThickness="0.5"/>
        <Border Name="BottomBorder" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" BorderBrush ="#007ACC" BorderThickness="0.5"/>
        <Border Name="LeftBorder" DockPanel.Dock="Left" BorderBrush="#007ACC" BorderThickness="0.5"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StatusBar Background="Transparent" MouseDoubleClick="TriggerMaximize" MouseDown="StatusBar_MouseDown">
                    <Image Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
                    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Content="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
                </StatusBar>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Button x:Name="Minimize" ToolTip="Minimize" Content="0" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}" Click="TriggerMinimize"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Restore" ToolTip="Restore" Content="2" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}"  Visibility="Collapsed" Click="TriggerMaximize"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Maximize" ToolTip="Maximize" Content="1" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}" Click="TriggerMaximize"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Close" ToolTip="Close" Content="r" Style="{DynamicResource TitleBarButton}" Click="TriggerClose"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

My MainWindow.cs (Code-Behind):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfApplication16
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SourceInitialized += new EventHandler(win_SourceInitialized);
        }

        private void TriggerMaximize(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TriggerMaximize();
        }

        private void TriggerMaximize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TriggerMaximize();
        }

        private void TriggerMaximize()
        {
            if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
                Restore.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Maximize.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Normal)
            {
                WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
                Maximize.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                Restore.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TriggerBorderChanges();
        }


        private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TriggerBorderChanges();
        }

        private void TriggerBorderChanges()
        {
            TopBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.5);
            RightBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.5);
            BottomBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.5);
            LeftBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0.5);

            if (Top == 0)
            {
                TopBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                BottomBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
            }

            if (Left == 0)
            {
                LeftBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
            }

            // need to test in dual view -if not needed, remove drawing and windows.forms (from refereance and from the using)
            //Screen currentScreen = Screen.FromPoint(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position);
            //if (Left == (currentScreen.WorkArea.Width - Width))
            if (Left == (System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - 1 - Width))
            {
                RightBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
            }
        } 

        private void TriggerClose(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void TriggerMinimize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
        }


        private void StatusBar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
                this.DragMove();
        }


        void win_SourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IntPtr handle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
            HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle).AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WindowProc));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// POINT aka POINTAPI
        /// </summary>5
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// x coordinate of point.
            /// </summary>
            public int x;
            /// <summary>
            /// y coordinate of point.
            /// </summary>
            public int y;

            /// <summary>
            /// Construct a point of coordinates (x,y).
            /// </summary>
            public POINT(int x, int y)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MINMAXINFO
        {
            public POINT ptReserved;
            public POINT ptMaxSize;
            public POINT ptMaxPosition;
            public POINT ptMinTrackSize;
            public POINT ptMaxTrackSize;
        };

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public class MONITORINFO
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// </summary>            
            public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MONITORINFO));

            /// <summary>
            /// </summary>            
            public RECT rcMonitor = new RECT();

            /// <summary>
            /// </summary>            
            public RECT rcWork = new RECT();

            /// <summary>
            /// </summary>            
            public int dwFlags = 0;
        }

        /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public int left;
            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public int top;
            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public int right;
            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public int bottom;

            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public static readonly RECT Empty = new RECT();

            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public int Width
            {
                get { return Math.Abs(right - left); }  // Abs needed for BIDI OS
            }

            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public int Height
            {
                get { return bottom - top; }
            }

            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            {
                this.left = left;
                this.top = top;
                this.right = right;
                this.bottom = bottom;
            }

            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public RECT(RECT rcSrc)
            {
                this.left = rcSrc.left;
                this.top = rcSrc.top;
                this.right = rcSrc.right;
                this.bottom = rcSrc.bottom;
            }

            /// <summary> Win32 </summary>
            public bool IsEmpty
            {
                get
                {
                    // BUGBUG : On Bidi OS (hebrew arabic) left > right
                    return left >= right || top >= bottom;
                }
            }

            /// <summary> Return a user friendly representation of this struct </summary>
            public override string ToString()
            {
                if (this == RECT.Empty) { return "RECT {Empty}"; }
                return "RECT { left : " + left + " / top : " + top + " / right : " + right + " / bottom : " + bottom + " }";
            }

            /// <summary> Determine if 2 RECT are equal (deep compare) </summary>
            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (!(obj is Rect)) { return false; }
                return (this == (RECT)obj);
            }

            /// <summary>Return the HashCode for this struct (not garanteed to be unique)</summary>
            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return left.GetHashCode() + top.GetHashCode() + right.GetHashCode() + bottom.GetHashCode();
            }

            /// <summary> Determine if 2 RECT are equal (deep compare)</summary>
            public static bool operator ==(RECT rect1, RECT rect2)
            {
                return (rect1.left == rect2.left && rect1.top == rect2.top && rect1.right == rect2.right && rect1.bottom == rect2.bottom);
            }

            /// <summary> Determine if 2 RECT are different(deep compare)</summary>
            public static bool operator !=(RECT rect1, RECT rect2)
            {
                return !(rect1 == rect2);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32")]
        internal static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MONITORINFO lpmi);

        [DllImport("User32")]
        internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, int flags);

        private static System.IntPtr WindowProc(
                System.IntPtr hwnd,
                int msg,
                System.IntPtr wParam,
                System.IntPtr lParam,
                ref bool handled)
        {
            switch (msg)
            {
                case 0x0024:
                    WmGetMinMaxInfo(hwnd, lParam);
                    handled = true;
                    break;
            }

            return (System.IntPtr)0;
        }

        private static void WmGetMinMaxInfo(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.IntPtr lParam)
        {
            MINMAXINFO mmi = (MINMAXINFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MINMAXINFO));

            // Adjust the maximized size and position to fit the work area of the correct monitor
            int MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 0x00000002;
            System.IntPtr monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);

            if (monitor != System.IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                MONITORINFO monitorInfo = new MONITORINFO();
                GetMonitorInfo(monitor, monitorInfo);
                RECT rcWorkArea = monitorInfo.rcWork;
                RECT rcMonitorArea = monitorInfo.rcMonitor;
                mmi.ptMaxPosition.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.left - rcMonitorArea.left);
                mmi.ptMaxPosition.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.top - rcMonitorArea.top);
                mmi.ptMaxSize.x = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.right - rcWorkArea.left);
                mmi.ptMaxSize.y = Math.Abs(rcWorkArea.bottom - rcWorkArea.top);
            }

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(mmi, lParam, true);
        }
    }
}
```

My App.xaml:

```
<Application
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" x:Class="WpfApplication16.App"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>


        <Style x:Key="TitleBarButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,7"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Marlett"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextBlock.FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" TextBlock.FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EFEFF2" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#007ACC"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: In your custom control like the image you shared, can you make the Visual Studio (icon) a button and show the ContextMenu from there when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes. I just need to know how to call that specific ContextMenu. Do I need to make one myself or I can call directly this one? (my control is based on window control)

Comment: please remove the extra code from your question.. this will help others getting the question quickly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The menu that you want to show is system `ContextMenu`. To work with that you need to import some `user32` functions as shown in the code below. I have launched the system menu on button click. You can launch it on any action, right mouse click etc

`GetSystemMenu` gets the system menu and `TrackPopupMenuEx` is used to display it. `PostMessage` is the send system command on menuitem click.

```
public partial class Window3 : Window
{

     private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;
    uint TPM_LEFTALIGN = 0x0000;
    uint TPM_RETURNCMD = 0x0100;
     const UInt32 MF_ENABLED = 0x00000000;
     const UInt32 MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;
     internal const UInt32 SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
     internal const UInt32 SC_RESTORE = 0xF120;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int TrackPopupMenuEx(IntPtr hmenu, uint fuFlags,
      int x, int y, IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lptpm);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem,
       uint uEnable);

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
        IntPtr callingWindow = helper.Handle;
        IntPtr wMenu = GetSystemMenu(callingWindow, false);
        // Display the menu
        if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            EnableMenuItem(wMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_GRAYED);
        }
        else
        {
            EnableMenuItem(wMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_ENABLED);
        }

        int command = TrackPopupMenuEx(wMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RETURNCMD, 100, 100, callingWindow, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (command == 0)
            return;

        PostMessage(callingWindow, WM_SYSCOMMAND, new IntPtr(command), IntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

Comment: Getting very close to what I want. I have one problem - the maximize item is enabled even when the window is maximized, same about restore (when it is not maximized) - how can I force it to act as it should?

Comment: updated answer for maximize menuitem enable/disable...similarly you will need handle other items

Comment: Works great, although I hoped it will detect automatically but whatever as long as it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to open the menu in the default position?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom control like the image you shared, make the Visual Studio (icon) a imagebutton/button and show the ContextMenu from there when it is clicked.

```
<Button Click="SomeEventHandler">
  <Button.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
      <!-- DO WHATEVER -->
     </ContextMenu>
  </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Then on the Click handler, just say **buttonName.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true**

More on how you can achieve this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.aspx)

There is already a dependency property that you can set to show the context menu. I am not sure what you mean by "Do you need to make one yourself or you can call directly this one"

Edit: I don't understand though why you are **recreating** the Window behavior instead of inheriting your custom window to the Window class and overwrite what you need to customize.

Comment: Yes, I can see you didnt understand me properly. I know how to make ContextMenu and call it. I dont want to make my own ContextMenu but to use the window's ContextMenu (with the restore, move, size etc... items) - I am pretty sure there's a way but I dont know how..

Comment: Saw it, 1st I am not sure I know how to inherit. 2nd I overwritten the whole design (made Window based on Windows 8 Design http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335343/wpf-net-framework-3-5-window-metro-style - cat take something pre-made because their target is framework 4+ so I had to make my own) + overritten some of the functions (for example: add borders when not maximized)

Comment: Can you show me your custom control? Both the XAML and behind the code if you have one.

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C3392940F5CF5F74!107&authkey=!APd2X3tDxWRfpL4 also edited my first post

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an MVVM application, in the ViewModel you just need to declare the property of the window and your command:

```
public Window Window { get; set; }
public ICommand MenuCommand { get; set; }
```

Then a Point property that gets the position of the mouse cursor relative to the screen:

```
public Point MousePosition
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.Current.MainWindow.PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(Window));
        }
        
    }
```

And for last in the constructor of your class:

```
public WindowViewModel(Window window)
{
    MenuCommand = new RelayCommand(() => SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenu(Window, MousePosition));
}
```

In my RelayCommand class I'm just using the ICommand Interface that executes an action as follow:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    
    private Action mAction;
    
    public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged = (sender, e) => { };
    
    public RelayCommand(Action action)
    {
        mAction = action;
    }
    
    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        mAction();
    }
}
```